# Call an object with user input from Scanner?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a card reader system. There are multiple card reader objects created in the main method with account ID passed into it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

private String Choice;
private String AccountID;

    Reader r1= new Reader("1234");
    Reader r2= new Reader("4321");

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Pick a card reader to use:");
    Choice= in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter your account number:");
    AccountID = in.nextLine();

}
```

I want to pick a Reader using the Scanner and be able to call methods from it like: r1.verifyInfo();

Is this possible using the Scanner?

Comment: Do you mean something like: `if ("r1".equals(Choice)) r1.verifyInfo();` ?

Comment: I mean if I type in "r1" for the first Scanner input, I want to be able to call the r1 object with that input.

Comment: if you have only two readers - using a hashmap is an overkill. A simple if/else will do the trick.

Comment: @alfasin That's true, but I assumed OP posted a simplified/unfinished example and there will be more Readers eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give names to the `Reader`s and put them in a `HashMap`:

```
HashMap<String, Reader> readers = new HashMap<>();
readers.put("r1", new Reader("1234"));
readers.put("r2", new Reader("4321"));
```

Then you can retrieve them based on the name you gave them (in this case `"r1"` and `"r2"`):

```
String name = scanner.nextLine();
Reader r = readers.get(name);
```